# Using cloudfoundry properties

Tags: java, tomcat7, cloud-foundry, session-replication

I want to use cloudfoundry properties as described in this section-
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html#accessing-cloud-foundry-properties
not in a spring xml file but inside a context.xml(let's say tomcat context.xml file) file that will help me do some research on session-replication in cloudfoundry. I want to get connection.host, connection.port etc in that context.xml file to specify a JDBC based session store.

But I faced problem in doing so as these properties work nicely in a spring configuration file but not in other files. Could anyone please help me in this ?

Comment: you want connection pooling